# PHPStorm и аргументы для скриптов

Tags: phpstorm

Я наконец [добрался до функционала run](http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/slowpoke_face_pokemon-t2.jpg) в PHPStorm. Тут же захотелось подцепить все консольные команды Symfony, но я не понимаю, как забивать команды типа `doctrine:generate:entities`, которые требуют дополнительных аргументов. Есть ли способы удобно это организовать (не редактируя каждый раз конфигурацию run и не создавая обертку вокруг команды, запрашивающую аргумент из stdin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается Symfony (*Symfony based, Composer, ZF*), то PHPStorm сам найдет команды:
File -> Settings -> Command Line Tool Support -> + -> Symfony.. дальше разберетесь.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо